# bot.polling funciton in a try-except block, do not run the rest of the code

Tags: python, bots, polling, telegram, try-except

In my python code, the polling function is in a try-except block

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

while True:
    try:    
        status = "Conected"
        bot.polling(none_stop=False, interval=1)

    except:
        status = "failure"

    print status
    #do something..
    time.sleep(1)
```

but when `bot.polling` is executed, the script never print a status and do not run the rest of the code.

i try adding "block=True" `bot.polling(none_stop=False, interval=1, block=True)`, but in that case, the polling dont get the telegram messages.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, my last answer wasn't as clear as it could have been.

So when working with try/except you'll want to make sure that you've got the indentation under the While look and the Try: and Except: (and Else, Finally if you're using them too).

Next, you want the action that you're looking for to take place in the try or except. So, here's what I'd do:

This would run and continuously loop once per second. If the loop's status was successful it would show connected, otherwise it would print "failure" then try the loop again one second later. If it returns an error it will print that it has an error. However, if you encounter an error it will then loop back to the top of the while True: loop. This is why you were not getting a print since the except instruction didn't include to print. Once the exception happens your code goes back to the top and tries again.

```
while True:
    try:    
        status = "Connected"
        bot.polling(none_stop=False, interval=1)
        pass     

    except:
        status = "failure"
        print status

    else:
        print status


    #do something..
    time.sleep(1)
```

This tutorial is extremely helpful for getting up and running with these try catch loops.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Here's an example of a try except I use that works:

```
token = 0
while token == 0:
    print("Welcome to the back office.\nYou will need to log in to contine.")
    sleep(1)
    print("="*5 + " Please log in " +"="*5)
    print(" ")
    email = raw_input("Email: ")
    print(" ")
    password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    authpayload = "grant_type=password&username=" + email + "&password=" + password
    login = requests.post(url+'/token', data=authpayload) #testing
    token = login.json()
    try:
        token = token["access_token"]
        pass
    except:
        print(" ")
        print("="*5 + " ERROR " +"="*5)
        print(token)
        print("Sorry please try logging in again.")
        logging.info("user login failed " + str(token))
        logging.info("user tried email: " + email)
        token = 0
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print(" ")
        print("="*5 + " You're now logged in " +"="*5)
        print(" ")
        logging.info("user login succeeded")
        logging.info("user email: " + email)
        sleep(.5)
        pass
```

In my case, I'm "Try"ing to see if the json response has an object with the key "access_token" if not, then I know something has gone wrong and I don't let the user continue. This then sends them back to the top since in the except area I make sure the token is set back to 0. Meaning this loop will run until my program receives a value for the access token.

I truly hope this helps! If it solves your problem please accept it!

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: @Nivek I've updated my answer to be more detailed and give you a resource to assist with try/except/else. Hope this is more what you're looking for.

Comment: @Nivek updated again with an example of a Try Except Else loop I'm using in one of my scripts.

Comment: @Nivek Any further luck?